# Day trip to castle(s) when staying in Bucharest

Tags: architecture, romania, day-trips, bucharest

Which castle(s) can be most easily visited on a day trip when visiting Bucharest. The ones I found were Peleş Castle and Bran Castle, are there any others that are worth considering instead? And what (cheap) options are there to get to them?

I was thinking about catching a train to Sinaia, but I wasn't sure whether it would next be doable to get to Bran's castle by public transport within a day and back to Bucharest? Or are we better of renting a car for a day?

Comment: So, today we made the trip. In the end we ended up just going by train to Sinaia and spent the afternoon there. We decided against going to Bran Castle because it's not really all that unique and this day we didn't have to rush that much (which I am personally fine with, but others in the group less so). Based on my research hiring a car might actually be the best option if you *do* wish to see Bran Castle as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [list of castles in Romania on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_castles_in_Romania), you can figure your favourite from this list. Reaching some of them within a day by public transport is possible, for example:

- [Bran castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bran_Castle) (nicknamed Dracula's castle) is located near Braşov, it is possible to take a train (2h45) and then a bus (45min) [to reach it](http://www.bran-castle.com/directions.html),
- [Peleș castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pele%C8%99_Castle) and [Pelișor castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peli%C8%99or) are located in [Sinaia](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sinaia), 1h40 from Bucharest by train,
- [Cantacuzino Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantacuzino_Castle), in Busteni, is 1h45 from Bucharest by train,
- [Iulis Hasdeu castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iulia_Hasdeu_Castle), in Campina, is 1h15 from Bucharest by train,
- [Făgăraș castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C4%83g%C4%83ra%C8%99_Citadel) may be a bit too far off, reachable after 4 hours of train

and the others, including [Corvin castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corvin_Castle), seem to be too far from Bucharest to be reached within a day. Whether a rental car is more comfortable is your choice, depending on your preferences (cost or comfort).